# How to use a hook in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, jsx

I have information in the state (`true` or `false`) that I want to display if is true this **Navbar** component, but when I use the hook, I get an error message:
[hook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bivza.jpg)

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

import store, { history } from './reduxStore';
import AppRouterContainer from './pages/AppRouterContainer';

import Feedback from './pages/feedback/Feedback';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import { useTypedSelector } from '../src/hooks/useTypedSelector';

const isAuth = useTypedSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuth);

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <AppRouterContainer />
        {isAuth && (
          <Navbar />
        )}
        <Feedback />
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create a wrapper component to have access to store in your context (I think your `useTypedSelector()` hook needs that access).
2. You can use hooks only inside a function, not just inside a module.

Check out this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

import { useTypedSelector } from '../src/hooks/useTypedSelector';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import AppRouterContainer from './pages/AppRouterContainer';
import Feedback from './pages/feedback/Feedback';
import store, { history } from './reduxStore';

const NavbarWrapper = () => {
  const isAuth = useTypedSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuth);

  if (!isAuth) {
    return null;
  }

  return <Navbar />;
};

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <AppRouterContainer />
        <NavbarWrapper />
        <Feedback />
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default App;
```

Also, I think you should move the `NavbarWrapper` component to a separate file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It looks like work. However I got an another Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>.
Do you know how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: @SweetCaramel yes, I know. Check out the improved answer, please.